# If there were a function mapping a set onto its powerset, would the unrestricted comprehension schema be true?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have the following exercise in a set:

> Cantor proved that there can be no function $\phi$ mapping a set onto the set of all of its subsets. Show directly that if there were such a mapping, then we would have an interpretation of “$\in$” which makes the unrestricted comprehension schema true, including the version with parameters.

I am not sure how one would go about proving this at all. For the schema to be true, it would need to have a model in which it (all of its instances) is (are) true, but there can be no such model, as far as I know.

Comment: That's the point. You are trying to show that under a certain assumption, you can derive something false.

Comment: For a hint on how to get started, if you have a bijection $\psi:X\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, you can define a new membership relation $\varepsilon$ on $X$  by $x\;\varepsilon\; y :\iff x\in\psi(y)$. You just need to show that there's such a bijection given the assumptions, and that the comprehension scheme would hold.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine That should really be an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - I will trust your judgment, then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the point. You are trying to show that under a certain assumption, you can derive something false.

For a hint on how to get started, if you have a bijection $\psi:X\to\mathcal{P}(X)$, you can define a new membership relation $\varepsilon$ on $X$ by $$x\;\varepsilon\;y:\iff x\in\psi(y)$$ You just need to show that there's such a bijection given the assumptions, and that the comprehension scheme would hold.

Comment: To the OP, note that any map $f:X\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$ - surjective or not - lets us define an $\{\varepsilon\}$-structure $\mathcal{S}_f$ with domain $X$ via $$x\varepsilon y\quad\iff \quad x\in f(y).$$

For example, if $f$ is the singleton map $x\mapsto\{x\}$ then $\mathcal{S}_f$ interprets $\varepsilon$ as equality. More interestingly, if $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the set of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, then $\mathcal{S}_g$ satisfies the axiom of **pairing**. And so forth.

Comment: Noah makes a good point: I wrote my answer assuming that you *also* want extensionality, which the question doesn't actually call for.